# sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-100] Database server not found

Tags: php, sqlanywhere

it's about more than one full day that i started sqlanywhere and i'm so interested to use it,

i worked before with sqlsrv for ms sql server and connection via php ,

but i have problem for connecting php to sqlanywhere

here is the warning message when i try to run test.php

---

Installation successful Using php-5.6.0_sqlanywhere.dll 
Warning: sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-100] Database server not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 44

### Connection failed

```
$conn = sasql_connect( "UID=DBA;PWD=sql" );
if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connected successfully\n";
    sasql_disconnect( $conn );
} else {
    echo "Connection failed\n";
}
```

---

I'm using xampp server php 5.6 and sqlanywhere 17 developer edition.

already i downloaded the php extension and copied on ext and also added the line in php.ini (extension=php-5.6.0_sqlanywhere.dll)

demo database i ran it with cmd : dbeng17 "%SQLANYSAMP17%\demo.db".
via cmd i tried this also :
C:>dbping -d -c "uid=dba;
SQL Anywhere Server Ping U
Connected to SQL Anywhere
Ping database successful.

but when i try via php it says: Warning: sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-100] Database server not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 44
Connection failed

please someone tell me what is the problem ?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved for me when I installed and used it on another system , I don't know I tried first on a system that MSSQL server was install and I couldn't run it and tried on another system that mssql server was not installed and solved :)
sorry for being late to answer and thank you very much for those who took time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP installation may have multiple files similar to php.ini. Make sure you are modifying the php.ini file listed in phpinfo(). 
- A web server such as Apache, IIS, or any web server that supports
   PHP.
 - PHP installed on the same computer as the web server. 
 - SQL Anywhere installed on the same computer as the web server.
 - The client software can be used as well. SQL Anywhere PHP extension

Refrance : https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/Getting+Started+with+SAP+SQL+Anywhere+and+PHP

Comment: thank you but really i did all the above things and still doesn't work.

Comment: Installation successful Using php-5.6.0_sqlanywhere.dll 
Warning: sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-100] Database server not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 44